# Adding section number after section title with titlesec package

Tags: sectioning, numbering, titlesec

I am having difficulty adding the section number after the section title. Normally the order is section number followed by section title. I want it to be the opposite. I am looking for what I should add to the following `.tex` file code:

```
\usepackage[compact]{titlesec}
\titleformat{\section}[runin]{\large\bfseries}{\thesection}{}{}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Your question was migrated here from [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7856693/latex-adding-section-number-after-section-title-with-titlesec-package?noredirect=1). Please register on this site, too, and make sure that both accounts are associated with each other, otherwise you won't be able to comment on or accept answers or edit your question.

Answer (score 15):

You need to use the `explicit` package option with [`titlesec`](http://ctan.org/pkg/titlesec). It enables you to "explicitly" state where the section title is printed using `#1` to denote the title. In this case, we place the title code in the `<before code>` section of `\titleformat`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[compact,explicit]{titlesec}% http://ctan.org/pkg/titlesec
\begin{document}
\titleformat{\section}[runin]{\large\bfseries}{}{0pt}{#1\quad\thesection}
\section{First section}
\section{Second section}
\section{Last section}
\end{document}
```

The general structure of title formatting provided by `titlesec` is via

```
\titleformat{<command>}[<shape>]{<format>}{<label>}{<sep>}{<before-code>}[<after-code>]
```

Since the `<label>` is no longer needed, it is explicitly inserted in `<before-code>` together with (after) the section title `#1`. I've placed `\quad` between the two components, but you can modify this to your like, using (say) `\hspace{<len>}` where `<len>` is any recognized (La)TeX length.

I kept your other settings for the sake of convenience since you didn't provide a complete MWE.

Comment: This is nice, but won't deal properly with `\section*`.

Comment: I haven't found the option "explicit" in my titlesec in teTeX-2.0.

Comment: @imz--IvanZakharyaschev: [teTeX](http://www.tug.org/tetex/) seems to not be supported anymore (last updated May 2006), and TUG suggests using [TeX Live](http://www.tug.org/texlive/). Do so and you'll have more up-to-date packages. According to the [`titlesec`](http://ctan.org/pkg/titlesec) [CHANGELOG](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/titlesec/CHANGES), the `explicit` option was added March 27, 2007. It may also be relevant to read [How do I update my TeX distribution?](http://goo.gl/CqWB1)

Comment: @Werner Thanks! yes, indeed, the version of the package in teTeX is too old.

Comment: The answer you provided is applicable in {article} documentclass. How to do that in {report} documentclass?

Comment: @EnosLolang: When I change `article` to `report`, I achieve the same `<title> <num>` layout for `\section`s.