# Setting a counter for sections

Tags: counters

I prepare a document where there are questions as follows and the relevant content

```
\section*{Question 1}
...
\section*{Question 2}
...
\section*{Question 3}
...
...
```

I want a counter instead of writing 1,2,3 such as

```
\section*{Question \qno}
...
\section*{Question \qno}
...
\section*{Question \qno}
...
...
```

where `\qno` will be automatically incremented and inserted as a number in the document. I read [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/21300/custom-counter-and-cross-referencing), but it's not something I need since I don't need cross-referencing.

Is there a way to initialize a counter and use it in LaTeX or is there an alternative solution for me to generate sections with name `Question #` in my document?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One way is to use `titlesec` to customize how `\section` looks.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\section}[runin]{\large\bfseries}{}{0pt}{Question \thesection.}
\newcommand{\question}{\section{}}
\begin{document}
\question
\question
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I borrowed the `titleformat` from [this post](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/32318/586) by the way. (Thanks, @Werner.)

Answer (score 7):

A direct solution to your problem is the following.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

\newcounter{quest}
\setcounter{quest}{1}
\newcommand{\qno}{\arabic{quest}\stepcounter{quest}}

\section*{Question \qno}
\section*{Question \qno}

\end{document}
```

However, this seems like an abuse of the section command. You should instead change the presentation of sections, or define a new environment.

EDIT:

See Torbjørn's answer for how to customise sections.

Comment: Thanks for the +1. I really do recommend Torbjørn's answer though. It's far cleaner than mine. If you do what I put above, you're essentially declaring a counter when the one that `section` uses is feeling lonely and forgotten.

Comment: I agree. T was unpleasant with using `section` out of each `question` part. Declaring a new `question` makes it easier to write and read.

Comment: Are you using sections in your document as well though, or is this for something like a problem set for some students?

Comment: Yes, it a very simple small document, it is a problem set for the students. I'm not using sections.