# How to change section headings to have Q1 Q2

Tags: sectioning

Can somebody help with changing the headings for my section?

Instead of having 1 2 3, I would like to have Q1  Q2  Q3 (and keep the automatic numbering).
Thanks

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Does http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/36035/setting-a-counter-for-sections/36042#36042 help?

Answer (score 1):

Redefining the `\thesection` macro will do what you want:

```
\renewcommand{\thesection}{Q\arabic{section}}
```