# How to swap section number with section title?

Tags: sectioning, formatting

is it possible to swap the numbering of the section block with it's title.

```
\section{Section}
```

like

> Section 1

instead of

> 1 Section

I use

```
\documentclass[fleqn,12pt]{article}
```

Comment: This depends on the documentclass you are using.  Can provide that information?

Comment: *A priori*, if the class is compatible, it's easy with `titlesec`.

Comment: This means you don't want to specify a title for the section, just "Section 1"?

Comment: To echo egreg, I think "My Section Title 1" looks stranger than "1 My Section Title".  Is that what you really want?

Comment: I want to provide a name for a section but
I don't like the order.
e.g. 1 Problem isn't the same as Problem 1.

Comment: To format sections: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/36609/formatting-section-titles if you want every `\section` statement to issue `Problem Nº` you can put the word 'Problem' before the `\thesection` and then issue `\section{}`. Or if a Problem has a name then `\section{Name}` and change the separator `1em` to something like `--` or whatever pleases you the most.

Comment: My gut tells me that you misunderstand the purpose of the argument.  I think you want "Problem 1", "Section 3", and things like that.  Instead, `\section{Euler's Theorem}` normally produces "1. Euler's Theorem".  You could rearrange things to have "Section 1. Euler's Theorem".  But having "Euler's Theorem 1." would be wrong.  If you want "Problem 1", et.c., I think you'd be better served by itemizing and using enumitem or a related package.

Answer (score 3):

By using the `titlesec` package with the `explicit` package option should give you what you want.  You need to add `#1` to the `<before code>` part of the `\titleformat` command:

```
\documentclass[fleqn,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\titleformat{\section}[hang]{\Huge\bfseries}{}{0pt}{#1\quad\thesection}[]

\begin{document}
\section{My First Section}
\section{My Second Section}
\end{document}
```

[image]

`#1` represents the words of the title and does not work when `explicit` is not used, `\thesection` is the number of the section, and `\quad` is spacing.

A simpler version would be:

```
    \documentclass[fleqn,12pt]{article}
        \usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
        \titleformat{\section}[hang]{}{}{0pt}{#1\quad\thesection}[]

\begin{document}
    \section{My First Section}
    \section{My Second Section}
    \end{document}
```

[image]

The form of `titlesec` formatting is as so:

`\titleformat{<command>}[<shape>]{<format>}{<label>}{<sep>}{<before-code>}[<after-code>]`

This is similar to the question asked here:

[Adding section number after section title with titlesec package](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/32317/adding-section-number-after-section-title-with-titlesec-package)

Edit, I'll try and break it down a little.  The documentation is a bit vague regarding the label section.

`\titleformat{<command>}[<shape>]{<format>}{<label>}{<sep>}{<before-code>}[<after-code>]`

`\titleformat{<command>}` is the part were you override an existing title command, such as `\section` or `\chapter`

`[<shape>]` defines the shape of the title, `hang` is the same as a normal title using `display` for example would yield a result similar to the standard chapter title format.

`{<format>}` defines the format of the title text and takes most standard latex values such as `\Huge` or `\bfseries`.

`{<label>}` defines the label of the section title but is no longer needed with the `explicit` package option and will be defined with `#1` later.

`{<sep>}` is the separation between the title and the first paragraph and takes any standard latex length such as `1em` or `12pt`.

`{<before-code>}` this is where we define the position of the title text with `#1` and then the number with `\thesection` giving a spacing between them with `\quad` (though you could use `\hspace{<len>}`).

`[<after-code>]` could be used to define underlines or such but isn't necessary in this example.

Comment: Is \thesection a counter, and \quad a spacing unit ?
And what is the label, I couldn't find any definitions in
the documentation.

Comment: I've updated my post with more information, please let me know if that helps @jam